# How to submit contact form7 with my custom button

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Am working on contactform7 plugin, when i click on custom button need to validate the fields and submit the contactform7, can any one suggest me the code.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.  Make an effort and post your code.  Otherwise hire a qualified developer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do using jquery and css.

First hide the submit button from form using following code.

```
.wpcf7-submit{display: none;}
```

Now in your custom js file or footer add following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#customid").click(function(){
        jQuery('form.wpcf7-form').find('.wpcf7-submit').trigger( "submit" );      
      });

});
</script>
```

This will work for you.

Comment: CF7 already provides basic validation.  And this code does nothing to properly extend that.

Comment: @justin can you please read the question ? I just give the answer regarding the question only.